# How can I make 4 column for desktop and 2 column for mobile using css flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am working on a page which has 4 columns for desktop and 2 columns for mobile and I wanted to use flex for it so please guide how can I do it

Comment: Using Media Queries, flex-basis and width's(min-width's). Still have you searched for it ? If so where is your code? What part is not running for you?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `max-width` of the children to 50% on mobile.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-wrapper > div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex-wrapper > div {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div>Column1</div>
  <div>Column2</div>
  <div>Column3</div>
  <div>Column4</div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the `max-width` in the media rule to match your preferred breakpoint.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kq5ozft3/1/